# Wordpress - changing name of attribute in links

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce in Wordpress and have a site such as https://example.com/shop/producer/myproducer/ but I would like to change /shop/producer/ into something else, like brands (as I have already site example.com/brands and I would like breadcrumbs to direct me there). How can I do that without changing the attribute name of "producer" for products in WooCommerce?

Comment: Check this link out: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/permalinks/ and you will find the documentation about it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to go to importation --> permalink and for there you can set your link name. But i think you have yet did the write choice that is Posta Name.

Also, you can go in your page, post or product page and change the permalink name for there (on the top just down to the title), if you want change the "sub permalink", you need change or the name of your category or the permalink in your primary page.